# Raise a column in a multi-dimensional numpy array to 2nd power

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, linear-regression

I have no idea how to raise a column to the 2nd power, I've done some googling and nothing came up.
I've tried: `X[:,-1:0] = X[:,-1:0] ** 2`, when `X` is a 47*3 numpy matrix, and I want to raise the last column to the 2nd power and it didn't work.

Comment: Try using this code `X[:,-1]**2` to update last row, -1 Supposed to last row

Comment: this slicing will give you nothing: `-1:0`  to get the last column use `-1` as mentioned in the above comment.